# How to implement the if statement properly

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a snip of code listed here. Basically is a database containing motel room numbers. There are 5 rooms in the data base. Some are dirty and some are clean. What I want to do is list all of the rooms into the listbox whether they are dirty or not. I'm having trouble figuring out the correct if statement to use so that I will list all rooms and print '--Dirty' beside the ones that are dirty.

```
def viewrooms():
rooms = Toplevel()
rooms.title('Room List')
rooms.geometry("800x900+550+50")

roomlb = Listbox(rooms, height=40, width=30, font="12")
roomlb.place(x=300, y=20)

conn = sqlite3.connect('roominventory.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM rooms")
records = c.fetchall()

for record in records:
    if record[4]=="N":
         room = str(record[0:2])
         status = "--Dirty"

    roomlb.insert(END, room + status)
```

Comment: `room` and `status` will be undefined if `record[4] != "N"`.

Comment: You should call `room = str(record[0:2])` first, then `if record[4] == "N": room += "--Dirty"`.  Finally `roomlb.insert(END, room)`.

Comment: Yes. The 'N' means the room is dirty

Comment: That worked but how to keep the room list without the parenthesese and commas?

Comment: If the first two fields are string, then use `room = "".join(record[:2])`.

Comment: It lists the rooms just fine now but they are displayed as tuple with the commas and parethesese. How to list without those?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that you don't reset the status variable so all the rooms after the first dirty one will be listed as dirty. The second thing is that if the first room is clean the status variable will not exist so roomlb.insert will fail also as noted above room will also be undefined.

These thre problems can be overcome with a two-line addition to your code:

```
...
for record in records:
    room = ...
    status = ""
...
```

Comment: It lists the rooms just fine now but they are displayed as tuple with the commas and parethesese. How to list without those?

Comment: OK do room[0] + " " + room[1] + " " + room[2]  instead of room. Oh and if you use my answer it is traditional to accept the answer and upvote it.